# Ubuntu updated and now the option to boot into Windows XP is missing

Tags: 10.04, grub2, dual-boot

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 10.04  and Windows XP. After allowing Ubuntu to update itself and installing some new programs, I restarted the system, expecting an option to choose for Windows XP. Unfortunately, the boot didn't give me an option to choose XP.

My XP is still on the drive, because I can access XP files from Ubuntu. I ran update-grub and got these results

```
g@G:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for g: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Professional on /dev/sda1
done
g@G:~$
```

But still no Windows.

What can I try next?

Comment: With a really long list of kernel versions, it's possible that Windows got bumped so far down on the list that you have to scroll to see it.  When this happened to me, I was pretty sure Windows had disappeared from the list until I figured out that it would show up if I just kept pressing the down key.

Comment: You are exactly correct, Michael. Thanks! I hate it when I make this kind of mistake!

Comment: Glad that fixed it!  I've reworded my comment as an answer below, so you can accept and answer an "close" this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the output of `sudo update-grub`, it looks like you have a long list of Linux kernels, and it is successfully seeing Windows and putting it at the very bottom of that list.  When you boot up, GRUB only shows a fixed number of options before it starts scrolling the list.  When you updated Ubuntu, it added yet another kernel version to the list, bumping Windows into the "not visible until you scroll" region.

At first I was hesitant to post this as an answer, thinking that I might be the only one to have made this mistake.  It's nice to know I'm not alone. :)

Comment: How do I "accept" this answer and "close" the question. I couldn't find anything in the FAQs. I'm sorry to ask another question whose answer will turn out to be obvious, but I want to give you the credit you deserve and not leave any loose ends.

Comment: There should be a check mark that you can click to accept the answer.  I think it will be located below the "score" for this answer (currently 4).